# Building array from object of arrays returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

So I have this `originalArray`:

```
[
  [
    {
       “name”: “Selena”,
       “lastName”: “Gomez”,
       “likes”: {
           “color”: “red”,
           “country”: “Argentina”,
           “state”: {
                “name”: “Buenos Aires”
           }
        },
        “phoneNumber”: “5555555555”,
        “isAvailable”: false
    }
  ],
   [
    {
       “name”: “Nick”,
       “lastName”: “Jonnas”,
       “likes”: {
          “color”: “blue”,
          “country”: “Argentina”,
          “state”: {
            “name”: “Buenos Aires”
          }
        },
        “phoneNumber”: “7777777777”,
        “isAvailable”: true
      },
       {
       “name”: “Joe”,
       “lastName”: “Jonnas”,
       “likes”: {
            “color”: “yellow”,
            “country”: “Argentina”,
            “state”: {
                 “name”: “Buenos Aires”
            }
        },
        “phoneNumber”: “9999999999”,
        “isAvailable”: false
      }
    ]
]
```

As you can see is an Object that has the form of `(2) [Array(1), Array(2)]` and I want to iterate over the object and get only the `phoneNumbers` items.

Expected output:

```
['55555555555', '7777777777', '9999999999']
```

I've tried:

```
const newArray= originalArray.map(element => element.phoneNumber);
```

But it returns `undefined`, actually I tried accessing with `.` like `originalArray.phoneNumber` and shows `undefined` too.

I also tried with this approach with no result:

```
var newArray = originalArray.filter(obj => {
  return obj.phoneNumber != null
})
```

Is there a way to iterate over the object, look up the `phoneNumber` key, and add those results to a new array?

Comment: `originalArray` is an Array of Arrays. Arrays do not have a `phoneNumber` property. I don’t know why you expected this `filter` to work. Arrays don’t have a `value` property either; none of your objects do. Have you considered flattening the array first?

Comment: So why if I do `typeof(originalArray)` it returns `'object'`?

Comment: Arrays are a special type of object and `typeof [] == 'object'``

Comment: @Danny Have you read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)? See [Why does typeof array with objects return "object" and not "array"?](/q/12996871/4642212).

Comment: I will, thank you.

Comment: flat(), map() and destructuring: `originalArray.flat().map(({ phoneNumber }) => phoneNumber)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

const phoneNumbers = originalArray.flat().map(element => element.phoneNumber);

Answer (score 1):

```js
const originalArray = [
  [
    {
      name: "Selena",
      lastName: "Gomez",
      likes: {
        color: "red",
        country: "Argentina",
        state: {
          name: "Buenos Aires",
        },
      },
      phoneNumber: "5555555555",
      isAvailable: false,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      name: "Nick",
      lastName: "Jonnas",
      likes: {
        color: "blue",
        country: "Argentina",
        state: {
          name: "Buenos Aires",
        },
      },
      phoneNumber: "7777777777",
      isAvailable: true,
    },
    {
      name: "Joe",
      lastName: "Jonnas",
      likes: {
        color: "yellow",
        country: "Argentina",
        state: {
          name: "Buenos Aires",
        },
      },
      phoneNumber: "9999999999",
      isAvailable: false,
    },
  ],
];

const phoneNums = originalArray.flat().map((element) => element.phoneNumber);

console.log(phoneNums);
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close, just needed to add map. Try this

```
var newArray = originalArray.flat()
.filter(obj => obj.phoneNumber!=null)
.map(obj => { return obj.phoneNumber;});
```

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this by :

- Flattening the multidimensional array into single array.
- looping through each object using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to fetch the phone number.
- This step is for safe side to eliminate the empty or null phone numbers using [Array.filter()](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

**Working Demo :**

```js
let originalArray = [
  [
    {
       "name": "Selena",
       "lastName": "Gomez",
       "likes": {
           "color": "red",
           "country": "Argentina",
           "state": {
                "name": "Buenos Aires"
           }
        },
        "phoneNumber": "5555555555",
        "isAvailable": false
    }
  ],
   [
    {
       "name": "Nick",
       "lastName": "Jonnas",
       "likes": {
          "color": "blue",
          "country": "Argentina",
          "state": {
            "name": "Buenos Aires"
          }
        },
        "phoneNumber": "7777777777",
        "isAvailable": true
      },
       {
       "name": "Joe",
       "lastName": "Jonnas",
       "likes": {
            "color": "yellow",
            "country": "Argentina",
            "state": {
                 "name": "Buenos Aires"
            }
        },
        "phoneNumber": "9999999999",
        "isAvailable": false
      }
    ]
];

const flatArray = originalArray.flat().map((obj) => obj.phoneNumber).filter((item) => item);

console.log(flatArray);
```